# Qt5 : output of bash process has input statements too

Tags: c++, bash, qt

I create a bash-process and connect it to my display function to display the output over my qTextEdit editor

```
m_Shell = new QProcess(this);
m_Shell->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
connect (m_Shell, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(showOutput()));
m_Shell->start("bash", QStringList("-i"), QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

I execute my command like this

```
QString cmdStr = "ls -l" + "\n";
QByteArray bytes = cmdStr.toUtf8();
m_Shell->write(bytes);
```

It gets executed well and I get the output too which I append to my qTextEdit like this

```
void showOutput()
{
    QByteArray strdata = bashProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    qTextEditPtr->append(strdata);
}
```

But the output over the qTextEdit has strange input characters too, please see this pic

[image]

Why is this ls and ll commnads coming too and that also new line separated and sometime together

Comment: Having an actual terminal is kinda messy (or at least complex). What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to eliminate the input coming along with the output for a command, but then its kind of messy to do that because sometimes it comes in one line sometimes in multiple line... my command "whoami" come in one line or "who" and "ami" in separate lines or "whoam" and "i" separate

Comment: What I want to accomplish is something like an interactive shell for my own programming language. Just like we have for 'R' or maybe you can say something like "python" terminal that we get when we type python over the bash terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that [QTextEdit::append()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append) appends a *paragraph*, but the text you read is not split by paragraphs, it can be split anywhere. So you don't want to be adding extra paragraph breaks there!

Solution is to use something else to insert text, for example [get a copy of the text cursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor) and [move it to the end](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#movePosition) (because user may have moved the cursor), then [insert text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertText) using the cursor:

```
void showOutput()
{
    QByteArray strdata = bashProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    QTextCursor cursor = qTextEditPtr->textCursor(); // get copy of text cursor
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End); // make sure we're appending
    cursor.insertText(strdata); // add the text using implicit conversion to QString
}
```

Notes: Untested code, may contain typos etc. Using implicit `QByteArray` to `QString` conversion may use different text encoding that what the terminal uses, so characters outside 7-bit ASCII may be converted wrong (easy to see as funny characters in the text edit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply hyde, but still the same result.

Comment: I kind of think there is some character that is being misinterpreted as new line and hence I have such outputs.

Comment: @rock Try looking at the data you read, print it with QByteArray::toHex()

Comment: Thanks a ton, your answer works. With temporary textCursor and cursor.insertText(strdata), I do not have input echo now and only the output. I initially did some mistake which I understood after the Hex printout.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strange at all. The interactive shell takes the input, and repeats it on the console. So that you can read what you type.

Instead of running an interactive shell, you should pass the command to the shell via the `-c` command line option, as detailed in the manpage for bash.
Pretending an interactive session to the shell is interactive is generally not a good idea.

If you indeed want to emulate an interactive terminal, you should use an appropriate widget, e.g. [QTermWidget](https://github.com/lxde/qtermwidget).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into QTermWidget.

Comment: How about saying thank you by accepting  the answer? :)